# How to float/clear list items in the same list

Tags: css

I have created a JSFiddle to demonstrate my problem **http://jsfiddle.net/02n979r2/4/**

All I have is a simple sign-up form with input elements in a list.

Some of these inputs need to be the full width of the container. Some need to be just half and hence floated to the left (so I can have two textfields on the same line).

However, once I've applied the float to the `<li>` wrapping the input textfield, any further `<li>` elements are not clearing the float above even though I have applied `clear: both` to the `<li>`

Can anyone please explain why its behaving like this and how to solve it?

Here is the HTML:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
<ol>
    <li><select name="department">
        <option value="sales">Sales</option>
        <option value="finance">Finance</option>
        <option value="logistics">Logistics</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li class="halfwidth floatleft"><input class="fullwidth" type="text" placeholder="First Name" /></li>
    <li class="halfwidth floatleft"><input class="fullwidth" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" /></li>
    <!-- Company does not clear the float and margin is lost -->
    <li class="fullwidth clearboth"><input class="fullwidth" type="text" placeholder="Company" /></li>
    <li class="fullwidth"><input class="fullwidth" type="email" placeholder="EMail" /></li>
</ol>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
li + li {margin-top: 10px;}
.floatleft {float: left;}
.fullwidth {width: 100%;}
.halfwidth {width: 40%;}
.halfwidth + .halfwidth {margin-left: 30px;}
.clearboth {clear: both;}
```

Answer (score 0):

These things don't need a list item. A nice way to style your forms is to use Bootstrap:
 http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly fine. However, due to having the following CSS rule `.halfwidth + .halfwidth {margin-left: 30px;}` the company li get's a margin-left as well.

The following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/02n979r2/3/) shows the same code, while removing the margin from that field.
Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Nope, because the Company field is not getting the margin-top: 10px.

Answer (score 0):

Ho about adding:

```
.halfwidth:nth-child(3+2n) {clear:both}
```

Clear every 2nd halfwidth, starting from the 3rd.

Comment: to make it easier, ignore the half width on company. I've changed it to fullwidth.